# Clone jquery mobile input field with data-clear-btn="true"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, dynamic-forms

Using jquery and jquery mobile I try to make a dynamic form. Input fields are created or removed so that always one empty input field is left.

This is my jquery code to achieve this (try it here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/SR864/17/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var total = 1;
    // add new field
    $("#bar").on("input", ".input", function() {
        // add new field
        if ($(".input").last().val() != "") {
            var newFields = $(this).closest("p").clone();

            newFields.find(":input").each(function() {
                var name = $(this).attr('name').replace('-' + (total - 1), '-' + total);
                var id = 'id_' + name;
                $(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id}).val('');

                total++;
            });
            $(this).closest("p").after(newFields);
        }
    });
    $("#bar").on("input", ".input", function() {
        // remove empty field
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).closest("p").remove();
        }
    });
});
```

I also would like to have "delete-buttons" inside of the input fields to remove the text from the input fields. jquery mobile provides `data-clear-btn="true"` for that. However, somehow the behavior of `data-clear-btn="true"` only works for the first input field - the new (cloned) ones don't get the clear button.

**Question**
How can I have the clear-buttons for the cloned input fields?

**Bonus question**
What is necessary to have input fields deleted when they are empty after the clear button is pressed?

Comment: Instead of cloning, inject a new one. Cloned ones will not work properly.

Comment: @Omar Is it possible to add a new one based on the original one? In my real life problem the form is a bit more complex and changing the code from cloning to injecting a new one would result in a quite inflexible solution

Comment: what do you mean by based on the original one?

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/pXF35/

Comment: @Omar thank you. But as I said this is only a minimal example - the original code is quite complex. Hardcoding the whole complex html-code in javascript would not be good style in my opinion...

Comment: ok, check the same demo, I've used `clone()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQM wraps `input` fields in a div `ui-input-text`. You need to clone `input` itself - not the wrapping div - change its' `id`, `name`, `val()`...etc. Then add it to `form` and *enhance* it using `.textinput()` function.

Moreover, you should wrap code in `pagecreate` event.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
    var counter = 0;
    $("#bar").on("input", function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).val().length === 1) { /* after 2 characters add a new input */
            counter++;
            var id = "input-" + counter;
            var input = $(e.target).clone().prop({
                id: id,
                name: id
            }).val("");
            $(e.target).closest(".ui-input-text").after(input);
            $("#" + id).textinput();
        }
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/pXF35/)**

Answer (score 0):

I had a check at the problem. By default the cross button (which is an  tag) has a class 'ui-input-clear-hidden' which keeps it hidden till you type. Though you are cloning the element after you start typing, the duplicate element also has this class which keeps it hidden (may be cloning is done before the class 'ui-input-clear-hidden' is removed). So I suggest removing the class 'ui-input-clear-hidden' from your cloned object explicitely as shown below.

```
$("#bar").on("input", ".input", function() {
    // add new field
    if ($(".input").last().val() != "") {
        var newFields = $(this).closest("p").clone();

        newFields.find(":input").each(function() {
            var name = $(this).attr('name').replace('-' + (total - 1), '-' + total);
            var id = 'id_' + name;
            $(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id}).val('');

            total++;
        });
        $(this).closest("p").after(newFields);
    }

    /* New line Added for Fix*/
    newFields.find('a').removeClass('ui-input-clear-hidden');
});
```

Comment: Thank you! However, this doesn't solve the problem - the button is displayed but it doesn't work...

Comment: oops! I didn't check that. I thought the problem was only with displaying. So when I saw the button I was like woww!! I tried using clone(true,true) option. Then the click is happening, but its clearing the first text box (orginal text box).